# Nginx- redirect to the encode url present in query parameter

Tags: nginx

Nginx is not redirecting when the value of redirect url is encoded using encodeURIComponent.

```
 location /redirect/ {
             return 307 $arg_target_url;
        }
```

When I enter url from the browser: `mylocalserver.com/redirect/?target_url=example.com%3Fx%3Dy%26z%3Dk` ,it gets redirected to `mylocalserver.com/redirect/example.com%3Fx%3Dy%26z%3Dk`. The expectation is, it should be redirected to url `example.com?x=y&z=k`.

However, when  $arg_target_url contains plain value, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your nginx install built with OpenResty? If so the [set-misc](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_unescape_uri) module is your friend